# Open source/Free network inventory management system with User-specific view

Tags: open-source, network-monitor

I am finding an open source/free network inventory management system (keeping track of desktops/servers/printers, like their warranty) which allows us to create different views or permissions for different users. For example, Regional users can only view/edit the inventory in their region.

I have looked into some tools like Spiceworks, Open-AudIT, OpenNMS. It seems that either you create an administrator with full controls over everything, or you alert some other users when there are incidents.

Could someone suggest a tool with such user-permission on view/edit?

---

P.S. We already have tools like SCCM to discover the devices. In other words we are looking for a presentational interface for browsing the device information we had. Also the device information are stored in SQL Server, thus the software should be running in Windows.

Comment: Do you care what OS?

Comment: Do you want devices to be auto discovered ? Also do you want something that will discover the devices details ? Or something where you just manually enter in everything ?

Comment: @user2616 See [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 1):

The combination of [GLPI](http://www.glpi-project.org/spip.php?lang=en) and [Fusion Inventory](http://www.fusioninventory.org/) can provide this flexibility, and can even use your AD user accounts for access and configuration.

GLPI provides the base ITIL oriented package that can do so much more than inventorying, and Fusion Inventory as a GLPI plugin handles inventory (and supports windows, solaris, BSD, linux, etc).  You will need to install fusion inventory agents on the clients.

This combination offers you so much more than just inventorying, if your needs expand.  There is support ticketing, project management, change management, and whole lot of other features, some of which require other plugins to be installed onto GLPI.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. but we would like to have one which runs on SQL server, since we already have data scanned by SCCM.