# Personal library-catalog-like software for keeping track of physical media

Tags: media-manager, barcode, catalog

I have a rather large number of CD's, DVD/s and other physical media around the house and I was wondering if there is any software that performs a similar function to [grocy](https://grocy.info/), an app that allows you to scan the barcodes of food you buy so it can notify you when you are running low on things, but for physical media.

This is pretty much the same idea as the systems libraries use to scan the barcodes of books, CD's .etc to allow people to check them out, however I'm mainly just interested in the catalog feature so I can keep track of which DVD's are located where and attach some notes to them to indiate if a DVD is broken/unreadable. This would be especially helpful for keeping track of which CD's I have already imported into my music library and which ones I haven't.

I'm looking for some software that:

- has an app or some other method for scanning the UPC/barcodes already present on CD's, DVD's, etc. tp add them to the catalog
- keeps track of the scanned-in barcodes along withadditional information like CD name/artist/album, if its been imported, and if the media is damaged in some way.
- is free and open source and ideally self-hostable

Comment: seems related: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/39255/simple-and-free-book-library-management-system-ils-for-a-small-library

https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/77606/web-based-userfriendly-and-open-source-stuff-managing-system

Comment: For movies, my [phpVideoPro](https://github.com/IzzySoft/phpVideoPro) could cover that – to a degree. Not really barcodes, but movie details can be imported from IMDB. I must admit I'm not really actively developing it anymore, but at least try to keep it working (updated it for PHP7 last year, for example). It's self-hostable (PHP+MySQL). To give you an idea, here's a screenshot [of the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLxKq.png) and [of the details view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RcCp.png). Not sure if it would fit your needs, though, hence only a comment.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks! I personally use apps like Plex, Kodi, etc for watching and storing metadata for the movies themselves, but thanks for the suggestion anyways! Tis question is mainly looking for a better/easier, ideally barcode-based way to maintain a simple database of which media has been already imported, where/in which box the DVD is stored physically now that its no longer needed, and any notes about unreadable or scratched disks that may be helpful. Honestly it seems simple enough that i could probably make it myself, but i'm curious if theres any existing options out there

Comment: Well, I didn't want to blow up comments here (I'm surprised the screenshots are displayed and not just the links to them). Need to see to get the demo running again: which medium is stored where or lent to whom is also part of the game. But yes, I already thought it might not really fit but wasn't sure… And sorry: no, I'm not aware of any such. Long time not checked as there was no need for me.

Comment: possibly related: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/20429/web-based-open-source-inventory-management-app?rq=1

https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3467/open-source-free-network-inventory-management-system-with-user-specific-view?rq=1

Comment: snipeIT seems like an interesting (mainly IT focused, but usable) open source Asset tracking system that might work for this since it fulfills all the requirements from the original post, even if it may be slightly overkill or not quite purpose-built for that task